# Heroku Error when pushing to staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

I have tried everything that I can find in StackOverflow as well as some other sites and my problem still exists.

```
Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
   Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
   Using --without development:test
   You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
   the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control

   You have added to the Gemfile:
   * libnotify
   * rb-inotify

   You have deleted from the Gemfile:
   * growl
   * rb-fsevent
```

Here is what I've tried and my Gemfile
https://gist.github.com/2244347

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine?

Comment: It's weird because I've seen this problem before but they all have to do with outdated versions of bundler (specifically 1.0.6). Would you try running `gem update bundler`? Shot in the dark.

Comment: > gem update bundler
Updating installed gems
Updating bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.1.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.1.3
Gems updated: bundler

Comment: Then trying a Push again was the same error. Is there a way to run this on Heroku?

Comment: Have you actually checked your Gemfile.lock into git? Do `git status`. Do you see `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: Ok bare with me for a moment as a cycle through possibilities. In your `Gemfile.lock` file, do you have a section titled `PLATFORMS`?

Comment: @MitchDempsey Yes I did. ("Nothing to commit")
Jon Yes there's this:

PLATFORMS
  ruby

Comment: Remove that section along with the content under it and see if you have any luck.

Comment: I removed EVERYTHING from PLATFORMS all the way down (Including DEPENDENCIES). Then I did a Git add / commit and pushed. I still go the EXACT same error. So I ran a Bundle install just in case (I know) but its still the same :-(

Answer (score 1):

I thought that I head read in your Gist that you tried removing Gemfile.lock from your git and re-adding it. But since I don't see that I'm going to assume that you forgot to commit it:

```
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Adding Gemfile.lock"
```

Answer (score 0):

`bundle install`

`git add Gemfile.lock`

`git commit -am "Updated
   Gemfile"`

`git push heroku master`